# In javascript, how to rename few properties of a huge object

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have an object with 120+ fields, and I am looking for a way to transform the object into a new object.

The new object is mostly identical to the original, except few fields are renamed and few fields are converted to Date object from milliseconds time.

Original Object:
`type: Record<string, unknown>`
Sample Value:

```
{
  "id":12,
  ...
  "created_at":1577999390226497 // Time in milliseconds
}
```

New Object
`type: Custom Object`

```
export class NewDto {
  client_id: number;
  ...
  client_created_at: Date;
  
}
```

I tried using slicing but it's not working. Sample code:

```
  const newObject = {
    ...originalObject,
    id: client_id,
    created_at: convertToDate(created_at)
  } as NewDto;
```

Comment: "I tried using slicing but it's not working." What's not working? The spread operator and then overwriting certain props _should_ work fine, so we need more detail about what behavior you're seeing versus the desired behavior.

Comment: If you don't need to keep the original object, then you could just mutate it.  `originalObject.id = client_id; originalObject.created_at = convertToDate(created_at)`

Comment: Getting compile error `If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Comment: Intention is to change the property name

Comment: You can't rename a property, you would delete the old one if no longer required. ->  `delete originalObject.id`

Comment: Is there a reason you’re using a `class` instead of an `interface`? Do you need `newinstance instanceof NewDto` to be `true`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend destructuring with the spread operator. Instead, I would use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject)). This is to avoid keeping some references of objects and arrays inside of your original object.

Comment: @JuanElfers yet that would destroy values like `undefined` or functions or others that are valid within JS but not within JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have few changes, you can just clone the whole object and then make simple modifications.

```
function transformed(orig) {
    // Clone the original.
    let cloned={...orig};
    // Add/Overwrite any changes
    cloned.client_id=orig.id;
    cloned.created_at=new Date(orig.created_at/1000);
    // Remove any renamed fields
    delete cloned.id;
    return cloned;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to rename a property. There is no shorthand for applying a function to a property value though; you have to do that manually.

```js
const {id: client_id, ...rest} = originalObject;
const res: NewDto = {...rest, client_id, client_created_at: 
                          convertToDate(originalObject.created_at)};
```

Comment: Why not destructure `created_at` as well?

Comment: There are 120+ fields, so was trying to see if I can clone the objects without typing every object property

Comment: @JDev You don't have to type out every field, only the fields that have to be modified (either renaming or changing value). `...rest` covers all other fields not explicitly listed.

Comment: still, there's a cost on using those `...rest` that you should take in count. Also, this is a shallow copying.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided is close to achieving the desired transformation, but there are a few issues that need to be addressed. Here's an updated version of the code that should work:

```
const newObject: NewDto = {
  client_id: originalObject.id as number,
  ...originalObject,
  client_created_at: new Date(originalObject.created_at as number),
};
```

In this code, we explicitly specify the type of newObject as NewDto to ensure type safety. Then, we assign the client_id field by casting originalObject.id to number since originalObject.id is of type unknown. Next, we use the spread operator (...) to copy all the fields from originalObject to newObject.

Finally, we assign the client_created_at field by converting the millisecond timestamp to a Date object using the Date constructor.

Make sure you have the necessary imports and that the NewDto class is defined properly. With this code, you should be able to transform your original object into the new object with the desired field renaming and conversion to a Date object.